# jquery autocomplete source code explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make jquery's autocomplete work to custom events. Potentially I might need to tweak source code. I'm trying to understand it but not sure how `'function( request, response )'` works. How this is getting called and where the parameters are coming from?

```
_initSource: function() {
        var array, url,
            that = this;
        if ( $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
            array = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter( array, request.term ) );
            };
        } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
            url = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                if ( that.xhr ) {
                    that.xhr.abort();
                }
                that.xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: request,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        response( [] );
                    }
                });
            };
        } else {
            this.source = this.options.source;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's getting called from different method inside autocomplete.

like here :

```
this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );
```

it's in _search method.